# Firebase storage rules unauthorized

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire, firebase-storage

[image: firebase storage rules]

i'm trying to upload files and unless im using alllow read, write, i'm getting unauthorized.

```
FirebaseStorageError {code_: "storage/unauthorized", message_: "Firebase 
Storage: User does not have permission to…2/dxbdIGnx2Qdm9MfTtG5e/if_spider-
web_345348.png'.", serverResponse_: "{↵  "error": {↵    "code": 403,↵    
"message": "Pe…n denied. Could not perform this operation"↵  }↵}", name_: 
"FirebaseError"}
```

I was wondering how does firebase knows that the user is logged in ? In my code i do not send any authentication while trying to upload files.

here is my code for uploading the file :

```
let uploadTask = storageRef.child(`user_content`).child(uid).child(upload.podcast_id).child(upload.file.name).put(upload.file);
  uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
    (snapshot) =>{
      // upload in progress
      upload.progress = Math.floor((uploadTask.snapshot.bytesTransferred / uploadTask.snapshot.totalBytes )* 100)
    },
    (error) =>{
      // upload failed
      this.flashMessagesService.show('Oh snap! please try again..',  { cssClass: 'alert alert-danger', timeout: 1500 })      
      console.log(error)
    },
    () => {
      // upload success
      upload.url = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
          //  upload.name is the name ref in firebase storage
      upload.name = uploadTask.snapshot.ref.name;
      upload.ref = uploadTask.snapshot.ref.fullPath;
      this.flashMessagesService.show('File was successfuly uploaded!',  { cssClass: 'alert alert-success', timeout: 1500 })

    }
  )
 }
```

i have an authentication service that requires a user to be logged in in order to even get to this uploading page :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {FlashMessagesService} from 'angular2-flash-messages';

import * as firebase from'firebase/app';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import  {Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap'
import { User } from '../models/user'
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
user: Observable<User>;
currentUser: firebase.User;
  constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private afs: AngularFirestore,
    private router: Router,
    public flashMessagesService: FlashMessagesService,
  ) { 
      // Get auth data, then get firestore user document // null
      this.user = this.afAuth.authState
      .switchMap(user => {
        if(user){
          return this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
        } else {
          return Observable.of(null)
        } 
      })
 }

getCurrentUser(){
  return this.afAuth.auth.currentUser;
}

getAuthState(){
let currentUser = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser;

  if(currentUser){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }

}

 googleLogin() {
  const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
   return this.oAuthLogin(provider);
  }
facebookLogin(){
  const provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
  return this.oAuthLogin(provider);
}
anonymousLogin(){
  const provider = new firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider();
  return this.oAuthLogin(provider);
}

  private oAuthLogin(provider){
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
    .then((credential)=> {
      this.updateUserData(credential)
      this.router.navigate(['/home'])
    })
  }

  private updateUserData(credential){
    const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<User> = this.afs.doc(`users/${credential.user.uid}`);
    const data: User = {
      uid: credential.user.uid,
      email: credential.user.email,
      displayName: credential.user.displayName,
      photoURL: credential.user.photoURL,
      accessToken: credential.credential.accessToken,
    } 
    if(!data.gender){
      data.gender = 'Unassigned'
    }
    this.flashMessagesService.show('You are now logged in ', { cssClass: 'alert alert-success', timeout: 3000 })

    return userRef.set(data)
  }
  signOut() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut().then(() => {
      this.flashMessagesService.show('You are now logged out ', { cssClass: 'alert alert-success', timeout: 3000 })

        this.router.navigate(['/']);
    });
  }
}
```

i'm using login with google in this example. still it is not clear to me how does firebase knows that the user is logged in , since i do not send any authorization upon uploading a file. if you can shed any kind of light on this, it would be great because i've been breaking my balls on this for 3 days.

Comment: Have you included "storageBucket" in the config on your project?

Comment: yes, i'm sure it is a rule problem .. because when my role is :  
    service  firebase.storage {
      match /b/{bucket}/o {
        match /{allPaths=**} {
          allow read, write;
        }
      }
    } 
i'm able to upload files to the storage.

Comment: Are you using the firebase authentication? I have a project that I use firebase storage with the same rules you post above and It works fine with firebase authentication. If you don't use firebase athentication, firebase never recognise you as authenticated.

Comment: but i'm using firebase authentication. in order to get to the website you have to log in , and in my code when i upload the file im using :
   let uid = this.authService.getCurrentUser().uid;
and this gets me the uid... but i don't understand how firebase knows that im authenticated .. i'm not sending any user data when uploading the file. @LucasDavidFerrero

Comment: When you login with firebase authentication the credentials is saved on the local storage of your browser. You could check in the dev tools if your application is storing the crediantials of firebase. After that, if you realize that nothing is been stored is because you're doing something wrong when you try to authenticate with firebase.

Comment: Plus, firebase doesn't use the uid to authenticate, instead it uses a token.

Comment: i checked the application local storage and i do have a user there.it has a key and a value (which has the uid, display name etc..)
i changed rules to --  allow read, write: if request.auth!=null;
it is still unclear to me why request.auth is equal to null .
by the way thanks for trying to help me.. i'm really frustrated about this haha @LucasDavidFerrero